# Cannot convert value of type 'Generic<String>' to expected argument type 'Generic<Any>'

Tags: swift, generics, compiler-errors, swift3

I'm perplexed... I don't even know what the compiler thinks might be going on, but I'm 90% sure this should be possible:

```swift
class Generic<Type: Any> {

}

protocol Foo {
    func bar(_ baz: Generic<Any>)
}

class SomeFoo: Foo {
    func bar(_ baz: Generic<Any>) {
        print("Got", baz)
    }
}

let someFoo = SomeFoo()
let generic = Generic<String>()

someFoo.bar(generic) // Compile error: Cannot convert value of type 'Generic<String>' to expected argument type 'Generic<Any>'
```

What's going on here, and what's the workaround? Surely there must be some workaround...

Comment: Why should `Generic<String>` be convertible to `Generic<Any>`? `(String)->Void` is not convertible to `(Any)->Void`. User-defined generic types don't support covariance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: But `String is Any`... if the function took in `Any` and I gave it a `String`, it wouldn't complain

Comment: `String` is an `Any`, and yet `(String)->Void` is not an `(Any)->Void`. My point is that this cannot be assumed to *always* work. Some languages allow you to specify that it should work; the current version of Swift isn't one of them.

Comment: To be clear, suppose you have a function `f(_: String) -> Void`. Then suppose you have `func callFunc(_ x: (Any) -> Void)) { x(42) }` which is totally valid code. If `(String)->Void` were convertible to `(Any)->Void`, you'd be able to call `callFunc(f)`, which is obviously invalid because `42` is not a String.

Comment: @jtbandes That's a great answer :D

Answer (score 1):

That's called covariance and it's not supported for user types in Swift (except Arrays as I know). BTW Objective-C generics support covariance in some way.
In your situation I'd choose from 2 options:

1. Make bar function generic
2. Create non-generic protocol which will be accepted by foo function and implement this protocol in your `Generic` class